# How to Implement Column Reorder in Angular Data tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

What I need

- I need to reorder columns in data table

Similar  example

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/colreorder.html

[image]

Problem

[image]

Angular Json

```
              "styles": [
                      "src/styles.css",
                      "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
                      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                      "node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css",
                      "node_modules/datatables.net-colreorder-dt/css/colReorder.dataTables.css"
                    ],
                    "scripts": [
                     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                      "../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
                       "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
                      "node_modules/datatables.net-colreorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.js"
                    ]
                  },
```

Angular ts code

```
                    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
                  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
                  //dataTest =[];
                  // Must be declared as "any", not as "DataTables.Settings"
                  dtOptions: any = {};

                  dataTest = {
                    data: [
                      {
                        id: 860,
                        firstName: "Superman",
                        lastName: "Yoda"
                      },
                      {
                        id: 870,
                        firstName: "Foo",
                        lastName: "Whateveryournameis"
                      },
                      {
                        id: 590,
                        firstName: "Toto",
                        lastName: "Titi"
                      }
                    ]
                  };

                  ngOnInit() {
                   
                    this.dtOptions = {
                      ajax: JSON.stringify(this.dataTest),
                      columns: [
                        {
                          title: "No move me!",
                          data: "id"
                        },
                        {
                          title: "Try to move me!",
                          data: "firstName"
                        },
                        {
                          title: "You cannot move me! *evil laugh*",
                          data: "lastName"
                        }
                      ],
                      dom: "Rt",
                      // Use this attribute to enable colreorder
                      colReorder: {
                        order: [1, 0, 2],
                        fixedColumnsRight: 2
                      }
                    };
                  }
                }
```

App Html

```
   <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover"></table>
```

Solution I tried

- Adding js Manually in Index.htm did not work

Added libs in dependencies in stack blitz as well

[image]

Stack blitz Link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tddmbw

Reference

```
https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/extensions/colreorder
```

Any suggestion is most welcome

Update ...

Rollback to old Stack blitz  version has no problem

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-jasgfw

But Column reordering not working.

Comment: You could use the Google build drag and drop features instead of the current library you're using? It seems more trustable... https://seoinfotech.com/change-table-columns-order-using-drag-drop-angular/

Comment: I only need to use Angular data tables lib please Thanks

Comment: any progress on this? did you figured it out?